# How to open and PDF or word document in the [Flutter]

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter

Question is simple, I would like to open any pdf or doc file via default App with using Flutter.

Think a Raised button that related my pdf asset, when user press it, pdf will be opened via Acrobat reader or etc. I don't want to use any web_view for it.

is it supported in Flutter?

Answer (score 32):

A good and simple approach to this is the open_file package which lets you open a file with the given path. It supports numerous different file types.

**UPDATE July 2022:**

As the open_file package has some permissions in the manifest that are not allowed anymore for Store uploads there is a fork of this ([open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex/install)) package that has this permission removed. The usage is the same:

```
import 'package:open_filex/open_filex.dart';

OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.pdf");
```

Comment: @s.j Is there some kind of error? Did you import it right?

Comment: yes I imported it correctly and now with static file address in the device I pass, it viewing files when it comes to view file with dynamic string variable pass like file path variable defined not working.

Comment: class EmployeeViewModel {
  EmployeeModel _employeeModel = EmployeeModel();

   String fname;

Comment: DON'T USE open_file package. There are two alternatives mentioned here https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/issues/174

Comment: @HasanEl-Hefnawy I updated the post. Although I would have appreciated it if you would have clarified why the open_file package should not be used anymore.

Comment: got this Error `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open_file on channel open_file)` 
I am using `open_filex`

Comment: @DebabrataSamal Have you completely reubuild your application after adding that?

Comment: Got this [Error](https://freeimage.host/i/screenshot-2023-01-17-15-25-00.Ha1trVR) while rebuilding

Comment: @DebabrataSamal have you checked with open_filex' github page?

Answer (score 18):

You can do this by opening google docs in a web browser :

In pubspec.yaml you need :

```
url_launcher: ^0.4.2+5
```

Includes :

```
import 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

Code snippet :

```
new RichText(
  text: new LinkTextSpan(
      url: 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf',
      text: 'Show My Pdf'),
),
```

LinkTextSpan class :

```
class LinkTextSpan extends TextSpan {
  LinkTextSpan({TextStyle style, String url, String text})
      : super(
      style: style,
      text: text ?? url,
      recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
        ..onTap = () {
          launch(url);
        });
}
```

Comment: This is not working with FirebaseStorage urls. I set read permission to true and write to auth != null. Any idea?

Comment: If you are not authenticating your users (i.e auth=null) via firebase auth, then you won't be able to read your database with these permissons.

Comment: @HemantKaushik did you get any solution for loading firebase storage URL in flutter webview?

Answer (score 6):

without downloading file,open from URL using the package
: [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#-readme-tab-)

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev/exapmle.pdf';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) package for this. Just pass the `path` of your document to the [launch()](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launch.html) method as the parameter.

Comment: `url_launcher` can not be use to open files in Android as per [Readme](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ flutter_full_pdf_viewer 1.0.6 ] Dependencie

Answer (score 3):

```
class EmployeeViewModel {
  EmployeeModel _employeeModel = EmployeeModel();

   String fname;   
                                                                                                                              void downloadFile(BuildContext context, String fileUrl, String fileName, ProgressListener listener) async {

    String _filePath = '';

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      String _directory = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
      print(_directory);
      _filePath = '$_directory/$fileName';
      //todo getting file name here
      print("file name" + fileName);
      fname = fileName;
      print("file fname" + fname);
      //APIKey.FILE_NAME: fileName;
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      Directory _directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      _filePath = '${_directory.path}/$fileName';

      print("file name" + fileName);
      //log(fileName);
      debugPrint(_directory.path);
      print("directory path" + _directory.path);
    }

    var response = await Dio().downloadUri(Uri().resolve(fileUrl), _filePath);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      listener.isProcessing(false);
      AlertMessageDialog(context,  UtilString.downloadCompleted, UtilString.downloadCompletedMessage, UtilString.open, AlertMessageDialogActionHandler());
    } else {
      listener.isProcessing(false);
      UtilAction.showSnackBar(context, response.statusMessage);
    }
  }                                                                                                  class AlertMessageDialogActionHandler implements AlertMessageDialogListener {

  @override
  Future<void> onPositiveButtonClick() async {
    String _filePath = '';
    String fileName;
    String _directory = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    //todo geeting right directory path here
    print("directory" + _directory);
    _filePath = '$_directory/$fileName';
    print("file path" + _filePath);
   // print("filename" + fileName);

    OpenFile.open("/storage/emulated/0/Download/GA55-Estimated-SHRIGOPAL-VERMA-2020-2021.pdf");  }}
```

Comment: in  this unable to get access of global varaible