# how to view pptx file inside my app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-html

I list all pptx files from storage now I want to display these files inside my app using a file path. I used different packages like power file view, flutter file reader. but engine load failed all time so i need a material related opening pptx files inside my flutter app

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
    pdftron_flutter:
        git:
          url: git://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-flutter.git
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:pdftron_flutter/pdftron_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _version = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();

    PdftronFlutter.openDocument("https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pdfref.pdf");
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize via an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String version;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      PdftronFlutter.initialize();
      version = await PdftronFlutter.version;
    } on PlatformException {
      version = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _version = version;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('PDFTron flutter app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Running on: $_version\n'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For more help read this [blog](https://www.pdftron.com/blog/flutter/build-a-document-viewer-in-flutter/)

Comment: how can i open file using file path.?

Comment: a already get path of docx file from storage now want to display them using path

Comment: And is this only for pdf or all files

Comment: this is for all type of files

Comment: but i am getting a files from device storage and i have file path like this 'storage/emulate/o/...' how can i use this now can you please help me with that

Comment: Did u try url_launcher: ^6.1.7

Comment: no  how to work on this ..

Comment: just pass the path in the url launcher

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623132/5197712

Comment: how you please add your answer in steps what to do with url launcher and then this pdftron to display docx from device

Comment: not working  . my file is local