# cannot parse a file in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Need some help to get the file content.

I using the flutter file-picker plugin to get a file. The plugin returns the path .

'/Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A509517C-AC3F-4F87-856A-145F61075E8B/data/Containers/Data/Application/FC2B634B-F7BD-48EB-9B80-920476E20DE8/tmp/com.xyx-Inbox/myfile.doc'

When I tried to read the content in Dart, I get the error

**flutter: FileSystemException: Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8'**

Here my code

```
Future<int> readFileStream(String path) async {
    print(path);
    File file = await new File(path);
    file.length().then((len) {
      print(len);
    });
    try {
      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();
      return int.parse(contents);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

How do I read the content?

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233934/how-to-open-and-pdf-or-word-document-in-the-flutter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that it is a word document that is binary, so you should read it as bytes rather than as string.