# How to open pdf file if it already exist in device in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String fullPath = "${tempDir.path}/boo2.pdf'";
print('full path $fullPath');    
File file = File(fullPath);
if (await file.exists() && Platform.isAndroid) 
   {
    
    } else {
          download2(dio, imgUrl, fullPath);
            }
```

Above code is used to download pdf file in flutter. If file exist in device then it should directly open it. and if it is not then it should download. Now the problem is I dont know how to open exist pdf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open and PDF or word document in the \[Flutter\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233934/how-to-open-and-pdf-or-word-document-in-the-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution would be to use [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex/install)

```
import 'package:open_filex/open_filex.dart';

OpenFilex.open(fullPath);
```

Comment: Yes. but this plugin is not working in mine project. Getting conflicts

Comment: Can you provide code example? What error are you getting?

Comment: I have use flutter svg, get, get_it, dio

Answer (score 0):

this will help you : open_file: ^3.2.1

this is the link : https://pub.dev/packages/open_file

you can open pdf by using this

Comment: https://www.clickdimensions.com/links/TestPDFfile.pdf

Comment: above link is my url

Comment: File file = File(fullPath);
                            if (await file.exists() && Platform.isAndroid) {
                              OpenFile.open(file.path);

                            } else {
                              download2(dio, imgUrl, fullPath);
                            }

Comment: I used OpenFile.open(file.path) but it is not working