# Blob response to pdf

Tags: flutter, pdf, blob

I have this API url response which is a blob response of a pdf.I need to download it as a pdf and open in the app.Please help me to find a way to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51544047/21211746
This might be helpful for your question